# Invalid entry Id/Uri

Tags: android, html, post, calendar

I post the data below to "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/private/full"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"><id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full</id><updated>2011-08-17T06:51:55.000Z</updated><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"/><title type="text">xuyao18@gmail.com</title><subtitle type="text">xuyao18@gmail.com</subtitle><link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=xuyao18@gmail.com"/><link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full"/><link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full"/><link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/batch"/><link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full?max-results=25"/><author><name>xuyao18@gmail.com</name><email>xuyao18@gmail.com</email></author><generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/calendar">Google Calendar</generator><gCal:timezone value="Asia/Shanghai"/><gCal:timesCleaned value="0"/><entry><id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k</id><published>2011-08-17T06:51:55.000Z</published><updated>2011-08-17T06:51:55.000Z</updated><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"/><title type="text">测试测试测试</title><content type="text"/><link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjBhMGI0ZWtyMDNtODJxYjg0c3BoajRqNmsgeHV5YW8xOEBt" title="alternate"/><link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k"/><link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k/63449247115"/><author><name>xuyao18@gmail.com</name><email>xuyao18@gmail.com</email></author><gd:comments><gd:feedLink href="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k/comments"/></gd:comments><gd:eventStatus value="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed"/><gd:where valueString=""/><gd:who email="xuyao18@gmail.com" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.organizer" valueString="xuyao18@gmail.com"/><gd:when endTime="2011-08-19" startTime="2011-08-18"><gd:reminder method="email" minutes="10"/><gd:reminder method="alert" minutes="10"/></gd:when><gd:transparency value="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.transparent"/><gd:visibility value="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.default"/><gCal:anyoneCanAddSelf value="false"/><gCal:guestsCanInviteOthers value="true"/><gCal:guestsCanModify value="false"/><gCal:guestsCanSeeGuests value="true"/><gCal:sequence value="0"/><gCal:uid value="20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k@google.com"/><batch:operation type="delete"/><batch:id>4</batch:id></entry></feed>
```

But I received the xml showing that I got the wrong Id/uri.

Anyone can tell me why?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
    gd:kind='calendar#eventFeed'>
    <id>https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/events/batch/1313568312069
    </id>
    <updated>2011-08-17T08:05:12.070Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event' />
    <title type='text'>xuyao18@gmail.com</title>
    <entry xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
        <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xuyao18%40gmail.com/private/full/20a0b4ekr03m82qb84sphj4j6k
        </id>
        <updated>2011-08-17T08:05:12.070Z</updated>
        <title>Error</title>
        <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
        <batch:id>4</batch:id>
        <batch:operation type='delete' />
        <batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri' />
    </entry>
</feed>
```